# Which one is true about this composition?

Tags: uml, associations, relationship, composition, class-diagram

I answer this picture with composition Car 0.1 - Engine 1.1.
Is it true?
Can someone explain about relation Car and Engine?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The question is somewhat confusing since the title mention composition,  but not the question you try to answer in the blue box.

We can deduce from the statement in the blue box:

- "*A `Car` has **exactly one** `Engine`*" means 1..1 on the `Engine` end of the association.
- The fact that a `Car` ***has*** an `Engine` and ***is*** not an `Engine` eliminates option (c), since the [generalization](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/generalization.html) represents an ***is-a*** relationship.
- "*An `Engine` has **at most one** `Car`*" means 0..1 on the `Car` end of the association.
- But "***at most***" implies that it could be less, so in other words, you can have an `Engine` with no `Car`.  This makes option (b) somewhat ambiguous, since 1) the [composition](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/composition.html) implies `Engine` to be owned by a `Car` which is responsible for its existence and storage; 2) nevertheless UML allows a part to be removed from the composite and survive independently (see note page 110 that clarifies this point); 3) but the composition symbol might mislead readers about the responsibilities regarding detached parts.

This leaves us options (a) and (d):

- option (a) technically fulfils the requirements:  the composition in that diagram says that `Car` cannot exist without an `Engine`, but the `Engine` can exist without a `Car`.  However the semantics of UML composition say it is a part- whole relationship, where then `Engine` would be the whole and the `Car` the part. This is nonsense, which eliminates option (a)
- option (d) technically fulfils the requirements: it is a normal `0..1`/`1..1` association.  The open arrow says that this association is [navigable](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/association.html#navigability) from the `Car` to the `Engine`.  It leaves unspecified whether the association is navigable in the opposite direction. The navigation is additional information which is not in the narrative, but it doesn't contradict it.

In conclusion, option (d) is the best one that validly fulfils the requirements.  It just adds some more information about the association.

Option (b) would be acceptable, but does not appear a natural use for composition in view of the perceived ambiguity for some reader regarding  the responsibilities for detached parts.

Comment: I don't think the statement _since this composition requires the Engine to always be owned by a Car._ is true. Its valid UML to have a [0..1] multiplicity on the whole end.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Could then please explain what would make (d) unsuitable in view of the sole narrative in the blue box (making abstraction of the bias introduced in the title, and without prejudice of the many composition examples with cars and engines that teacher persist to teach despite it does not correspond to a mechanical reality) ?

Comment: I agree that d) is the best answer, as the question doesn't mention anything about the composition constraints at all, and I don't think we should invent those constraints simply because the classnames are `Car` and `Engine`. We wouldn't be saying it should be composition if the classnames were `Foo` and `Bar` All I'm saying is that the reason you are eliminating b) is not correct. But looking "classes" in the image, I'm not even sure this is about UML.

Comment: Reading only the narrative we should even exclude d) as well, as there is no reason to include the navigability from car to engine. We only know about the multiplicities. But I don't see a "none of the above" option there.

Comment: @GeertBellekens ok, I've cross checked the composition with 0..1, and indeed, you were right: there's a note in the standard that states that this is allowed.  I'm reinsured, since the existence of such a note shows that this special case might differ from commonly existing expectations. I've edited my answer accordingly.  I still think (d) is the best option, but I recognize that (b) is valid option but maybe not a natural choice.